# Add Button to android.view.View

Tags: android

I have the next issue:

I have an Activity, where I want to try to add Buttons, this is my onCreate method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView(drawView);

    context = this;

    drawView.requestFocus();

}
```

This is the DrawView class

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

```
public static final String TAG = "DrawView";

private List<List<Point>> listaPuntos = null;
private List<Paint> listaPaints = null;

private int paintActual = 0;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    listaPaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    listaPuntos = new ArrayList<List<Point>>();

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    listaPaints.add(paint);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    for(int i=0; i<listaPaints.size(); i++){
        Paint paint = listaPaints.get(i);
        Point punto = null;
        if(listaPuntos.size()!=0 && listaPuntos.size()>i){
            List<Point> puntos = listaPuntos.get(i);
            for (Point point : puntos) {

                if(punto == null){
                    punto = point;
                }
                canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, punto.x, punto.y, paint);
                punto = point;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = event.getX();
        point.y = event.getY();
        point.paintPunto = paintActual;
        if(listaPuntos.size()<=paintActual){
            listaPuntos.add(new ArrayList<Point>());
        }
        listaPuntos.get(paintActual).add(point);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }else{
        paintActual++;
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        listaPaints.add(paint);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Anybody knows how can I add Buttons to this Activity?? I would like to add a Button to be able to make an action and I completely can´t!!

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only ViewGroup(LinearLayout,RelativeLayout) can have children.What you are doing is that you are making the DrawView as the content view of your activity which is not a container(ViewGroup) hence, you cannot add any other view(child) to it. 
The solution to you problem is:

- Create a xml layout file with a ViewGroup as the parent(LinearLayout, RelativeLayout,etc) containing other views or empty.
- Create an instance of the DrawView.
- Add this instance to the ViewGroup
- Similarly create instance of other views and add them to the parent if you want to add views dynamically.
  here is sample code for this:

Suppose LinearLayout with id as parent is the parent of the xml layout then:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
//creating instance of custom view
DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this);
//adding custom view as the first child
parent.addView(drawView,0);
//adding button dynamically
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Ok");
parent.addView(btn,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should make a xml file and must use it like setContentView (R.layout.filename) and because you are trying to merge your other page contents to this xml you should include layout by  now you can use this page id and can implement your any functions. **So better would be if you add button in other xml and then include it in your new desired xml**. this is a proper way... hope you understood what i mean. otherwise you can search  in developer.android.com

Answer (score 1):

You should create an XML layout file, that you will associate with your activity with the setContentView() call in onCreate().

Your layout will contain your own view, buttons, and whatever you like.